# Should I have used a CoreData predicate to populate my UITableview?

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, core-data, nspredicate

I had an old app that I rebuilt using CoreData and Swift 2. This is my first go at Coredata, so I'm sure I'm not doing everything the most efficient way possible. For example, I have 2 entities in Coredata, a Person entity and a Statement entity. The person entity has a relationship of "to many" to the Statement entity, the Statement entity has a relationship of "To One" to the Person entity. So basically my Person object is able to have multiple Statement objects. This is all working and I am able to add them into CoreData successfully.

Next I have a UIViewController with a UITableView inside of it. I have the tableview's Selection dropdown set to Multiple Sections. I have 2 sections assigned for the table view.

When I grab the CoreData Entities I place them into an array so that I am able to use that array and fill the tableview.

```
 var persons: [Person]!
 persons = try coreDataStack.context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [Person]
```

After that (and I think this is where things could be simplier) I break that array into 2 different arrays so that each Section in the Table view has it's own data source. I think this is where I could use a CoreData NSPredicate, but after looking at some tutorial and reading a couple of chapters of a book I have on Coredata, I still don't really understand how to use them. So instead this is what I'm doing to make 2 different arrays from the array I created from Coredata.

```
for(var i = 0; persons?.count > i; i++){
        newNumber = 0.00
        print("\(persons?[i].statements?.count) this is the statements count")

        if(persons?[i].statements?.count > 0){

            print("YES statements")
            //persons[i].statements
            for(var x = 0; persons[i].statements?.count > x; x++){

                //print( "\(persons[i].statements?[x].name) this is the name " )
                let statementNumber = persons[i].statements?[x] as? Statement
                //print(statementNumber?.amount)

                newNumber = newNumber + Double((statementNumber?.amount)!)
                //print(newNumber)
            }
            // check the new number and see if it's positive or negative
            if(newNumber >= 0){
                positiveeArray.append(persons[i])
                //print("\(positiveArray.count) This is the count of the posve array")
            }
            else{
                negativeArray.append(persons[i])
                //print("\(negativeArray.count) This is the count of the negative array")
            }

        }else{

            print("there are no statements add this person to the positive array")
            positiveArray.append(persons[i])
        }
    }
```

Basically each Statement entity has a property of amount. I want to check to see if that property is a positive or negative number. Again this system works, but it just seems like it's a ton of hoops to jump through to access that data.

After this I take these 2 arrays (positive & negative) and use them to populate the different sections of my UITableView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("personCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PersonTableViewCell

    //print("\(persons?[indexPath.row].statements?.count) this is the count to use")
    //print("\(indexPath.row) this is the index row")

    var numberForDispay = 0.00

    switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        if(positiveArray[indexPath.row].statements?.count != 0){

            for(var i = 0; positiveArray[indexPath.row].statements?.count > i; i++){

                let statementNumber = positiveArray[indexPath.row].statements?[i] as? Statement
                //print(statementNumber?.amount)
                numberForDispay = numberForDispay + Double((statementNumber?.amount)!)

                // this will make negative numbers positive
                numberForDispay = fabs(numberForDispay)

                let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

                cell.statementAmount.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberForDispay)
                //print("\(formatter) this is the number to use")
            }
        }else{
            cell.statementAmount.text = "$0.00"
        }
    case 1:
        if(negativeArray[indexPath.row].statements?.count != 0){

            for(var i = 0; negativeArray[indexPath.row].statements?.count > i; i++){

                let statementNumber = negativeArray[indexPath.row].statements?[i] as? Statement
                //print(statementNumber?.amount)
                numberForDispay = numberForDispay + Double((statementNumber?.amount)!)

                // this will make negative numbers positive
                numberForDispay = fabs(numberForDispay)

                let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
                formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

                cell.statementAmount.text = formatter.stringFromNumber(numberForDispay)
                //print("\(formatter) this is the number to use")
            }
        }else{
            cell.statementAmount.text = "$0.00"
        }
    default: ""
    }

    switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            cell.personName.text = postitiveArray[indexPath.row].name
            cell.backgroundColor = Styles.blueColor();
        case 1:
            cell.personName.text = negativeArray[indexPath.row].name
            cell.backgroundColor = Styles.redColor();

        default: cell.personName.text = "hello"
    }

    cell.personName.textColor = Styles.whiteColor()
    cell.statementAmount.textColor = Styles.whiteColor()

    // will make the divide line full width
    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 0)
    if (cell.respondsToSelector("preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins")){
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
    }

    // set the accessory icon color
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    return cell
}
```

Again this works, but i'm hoping that I'm able to clean up the amount of code that I have and streamline this process. I am coming from a flash / AS3 background. I know this is a long post, so if you got this far, THANK YOU! I just want to make sure I'm not creating more work for myself when I work on these apps.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a `NSFetchedResultsController`. You could even use two, one for each section. You get a lot of optimizations in memory, database access and performance.

Here are the 2 predicates, which you add to the fetch request of the fetched results controllers (fetching `Statement` objects):

```
NSPredicate(format: "amount < 0")
NSPredicate(format: "amount >= 0")
```

Return `2` as number of sections, and the `fetchedObjects.count` of the corresponding fetched results controller as `numberOfRowsInSection`.

You could do this with a single fetched results controller as well. But you would have to hard-code into the database a flag indicating to which section each amount belongs to. So whenever you set the amount, you would automatically have the entity object set its plus/minus flag.

BTW, rather than iterating through items, you can be much more concise in Swift (not only with managed objects but with any kind of object). E.g.

```
let negative = allStatements.filter { $0.amount < 0 }
let positive = allStatements.filter { $0.amount >= 0 }
```

Note that there are also aggregate functions available to Core Data. The sum of all statement amounts of a person would be

```
let sum = person.valueForKeyPath("@sum.amount") as! NSNumber
```

With this technique, you could have a `sum` attribute of `Person` that is updated whenever you set the amount of a `Statement`.

So your to `Person` predicates would be

```
NSPredicate(format: "sum < 0")
NSPredicate(format: "sum >= 0")
```

Comment: An additional advantage of `NSFetchedResultsController` is that it can make reacting to changes easier. As shown in the question you would have to repeat the process of building these collections whenever a `Statement` changes.

Comment: @Mundi Don't those predicates and keypaths need `statements.@sum.amount`, since the table view is showing `Persons`?

Comment: Right the predicates are based on a `Statement` fetch. I corrected this. Unfortunately, you cannot use collective operators in fetched results controllers or fetch requests.